# How do I add paginator to thid django code?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a system where users can view complaints they have registered on one page. But the problem is that only four complaints can be viewed at a time on the page. How can I add pageinator to the code so that the next four complaints can be viewed on the other page in the correct format and template:

views.py:

```
def History(request):
  complaint_data = Complaint.objects.filter(user=request.user) 
  context = { 'complaint':complaint_data }
  return render(request, 'myHistory.html', context)
```

template:

```
<!-- Middle Container -->
    <div class="col-lg middle middle-complaint-con">
        <i class="fas fa-folder-open fa-4x comp-folder-icon"></i>
        <h1 class="all-comp">My Complaints</h1>
        <p class="all-comp-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

        {%for c in complaint %}
        <a href="{% url 'Complaint' c.pk %}" style="color:black;">
            <div class="container comp-con-{{forloop.counter0}}">
                <p style="color: #D37A19; margin-left: -130px; margin-top: -5px;">Report number:</p>
                <p class="history-level-1">{{c.reportnumber}}</p>
                <p class="comp-title-1">{{c.event_type}}</p>
                <p class="comp-sub-1">{{c.event_text|truncatechars:85}}</p>
            </div>
        </a> {%endfor%}
    </div>
```

css:

```
enter code h.comp-con-0 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 11px 8px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 140px;
        left: 160px;
        top: 190px;
        background: #FFEEDB;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 25%);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    .comp-con-1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 140px;
        left: 160px;
        top: 400px;
        background: #FFEEDB;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    .comp-con-2 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 8px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 140px;
        left: 610px;
        top: 190px;
        background: #FFEEDB;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    .comp-con-3 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 10px 9px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 140px;
        left: 610px;
        top: 400px;
        background: #FFEEDB;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

I basically four css cards for four complaints and have a for.loopcounter to count the complaints in the html. How can I set the forloopcounter back to zero when the page changes to a new one. More importantly how do I add pagination to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Pagination You Should Consider Django Documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
def pagination_complaint(request, page_no):
    complaint_data_paginator = Paginator(complaint_data, 4)
    paginator_obj = complaint_data_paginator.get_page(page_no)
    context = {'complaint':paginator_obj}
    return render(request, "<your-app-name>/ajax_complaint.html", context)
```

Create a new template in your app as ajax_complaint.html

```
{%for c in complaint %}
        <a href="{% url 'Complaint' c.pk %}" style="color:black;">
            <div class="container comp-con-{{forloop.counter0}}">
                <p style="color: #D37A19; margin-left: -130px; margin-top: -5px;">Report number:</p>
                <p class="history-level-1">{{c.reportnumber}}</p>
                <p class="comp-title-1">{{c.event_type}}</p>
                <p class="comp-sub-1">{{c.event_text|truncatechars:85}}</p>
            </div>
        </a> {%endfor%}
```

create a new URL in urls.py for getting pagination!

```
path('<int:page_no>/', pagination_complaint)
```

now in your first template you have to add the ajax!
For adding data in the template add a new div with id="items" (it can be anything but I am using it)
Now I am going to use jQuery here! so make sure to import it in the template!

```
items = document.getElementsById("items");
  $.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    URL: "<your pagination URL>/<page_no>/",
    success: function (response) {
      items.innerHTML = items.innerHTML + response
    }
})
```

Comment: Like what do I add in my template? How do I change my template? I tried going through this but rn I don't understand it at all

Comment: do you wanna add ajax to get the data on the template without reloading the page?

Comment: yeah, that would be better

Comment: I've added ajax in the solution! it's the same solution that I'm using on my website SidTube(sidtu.be) which is a social networking platform! please mark it as a best solution! thanks!